# strong typed vue3 component with defineComponent

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Here is a minimal example:

```js
import { defineComponent, h } from "vue";

export const Test = defineComponent<{ foo: string }>(
  (props: { foo: string }) => {
    return () => h("div", `Hello ${props.foo?.toString()}`);
  }
);
```

The issue here is when I am using this component, `<Test :foo="5" />` is not strong typed: I could have used `foo2`property instead, nothing tells me it doesn't exists.

Here, the completion doesn't tell me there is a property `foo`
[image]

How can I declare the `foo` property so that it is taken into account when I use my component ?

Comment: This works for me. How are you importing `Test`? Do you have Volar installed?

Answer (score 0):

As peer @Yitz recommandation, I tried Vscode with Volar, which works indeed perfectly.

I am using Webstorm/Intellij. I also forced Volar with webstorm and obtain magically a great error
[image]

[image]

BUT, I still don't have completion in Webstorm (working in VSCode...).

I guess it is more a IDE integration issue than a vue issue here.